# What possible 3D model formats are accepted in KML?

Tags: 3d, kml, google-earth, collada, nevron

I'm new to KML and from the following reference I know that a 3D model of COLLADA format can be referred in a KML file.
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/models

I have created a 3D model using Nevron Vision .NET. But in order for me to render it in google earth I have to convert it into a .kmz file. A .kmz file contains .kml and .dae files. So I have to convert my 3D Nevron model into .dae format.

I want to know if

1. KML accepts formats other than .dae for 3D models.
2. anyone has rendered a Nevron 3D model in google earth.

Thanks!

P.S. Why Nevron you ask? Well, it's because I've managed to create an irregular shape successfully using it and I would prefer to convert the existing model into a format compatible with google earth than create a 3D model from scratch for rendering it in google earth.

Answer (score 2):

Google Earth and KML only support 3D models in COLLADA format (.dae files).  They support the COLLADA Common Profile, except that it only supports triangles and lines as primitives (with triangle limits), and it does not support animation, skinning or external geometry references.

You should be able to convert from other formats to COLLADA using SketchUp or other packages.

More details as well as KML elements specific to including a Model can be found in the KML Reference section on the  tag:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#model